# Read Json list inside stream (Method stream to string)

Tags: c#, json, list, stream

I need to read Parklist item in my Json stream. When I try this with string variable, it work :

```
string jsonString = "[{\"Project\":\"example\", \"Ref\":\"001BC50C70000A21\", \"Latitude\":43.643166, \"Longitude\":1.454769, \"ParkList\": [{\"Id\":\"001BC50C70000A21P1\", \"State\":1, \"DateTime\":\"2018-02-15T08:07:18.987Z\"}, {\"Id\":\"001BC50C70000A21P2\",\"State\":1,\"DateTime\":\"2018-02-15T08:11:41.824Z\"}]}]";

List<KMessage> kMsg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KMessage>>(jsonString);
foreach (Parklist item in kMsg[0].Parklist)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Id: " + item.ParkId + " State: " + item.ParkState + " DateTime: " + item.ParkDateTime);
}
```

But when I try to convert stream in string for doing same things, Parklist is empty in the new string (each other variable is ok in text var) :

```
// convert stream to string
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(KStream);
string text = reader.ReadToEnd();

List<KMessage> kMsg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KMessage>>(text);
foreach (Parklist item in kMsg[0].Parklist)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Id: " + item.ParkId + " State: " + item.ParkState + " DateTime: " + item.ParkDateTime);
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you get in `text `?

Comment: [{
"Project":"example", 
"Ref":"001BC50C70000A21", 
"Latitude":43.643166, 
"Longitude":1.454769, 
"ParkList":
 [{"Id":"001BC50C70000A21P1", 
 "State":1, 
 "DateTime":"2018-02-15T08:07:18.987Z"
 },
 {"Id":"001BC50C70000A21P2",
 "State":1,
 "DateTime":"2018-02-15T08:11:41.824Z"
 }]
}]